# Webpack not including exported components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a React application, and I'm building the React components inside a seperate library so that it can be shared throughout other applications. As the React Components are private, they're installed in NPM via git+ssh, rahter than as an NPM package.

### **The basics:**

My component Library has this structure:

```
-- components
---- component1.jsx
---- component2.jsx
---- index.js
-- package.json
```

The library's `package.json` file looks basically like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-react-components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Collection of React components",
  "main": "components/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
     ...
  }
}
```

The `components/index.js` file looks like this

```
export * from './component1';
export * from './component2';
```

Each component is written like this:

```
export const SomeComponent = () => { ... };
```

My application references these components like this

```
import { SomeComponent } from 'my-react-components';
```

My NPM dependency looks like this

```
"my-react-components": "git+ssh://{gitaddress}"
```

[Here's my applications webpack config](http://jsbin.com/waxepipeja/edit?html,js,output)

Since I'm developing this library in unison with my application, I have been using a symlink from the library folder to the application's node_modules folder to allow the references. This has been working, and is continuuing to work fine.

### **The problem**

When I don't use a symlink and instead use the version installed by NPM, babel or webpack or some part of the puzzle suddenly stops building my component library, and instead of referencing the components, I end up with the `export * from ...` tags in my compiled bundle. Cleaning the package and returning to the symlink method, and everything works fine again.

Webpack shows no errors, everything appears to build fine. I can see the difference in output however, in the symlink method, I can see each file being written into the bundle:

```
[1] ./node_modules/my-react-components/components/component1.jsx
[2] ./node_modules/my-react-components/components/component1.jsx

// Something like that I just made that up, 
// the point is I see the paths for components that are being referenced.
```

When I don't use the symlink I instead just see something like

```
[1] ./node_modules/my-react-components/components/index.js
```

and as previously mentioned, that file is basically dropped straight in, no babel, or checking imports or anything.

So why does this happen with an NPM installed module, but not the exact same files in the exact same location through a symlink?

Just to note they are definitely the exact same files, I've done this immediately after pushing my lib and making no changes, deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling, re-symlinking etc. The difference in the two methods is reproducable every time.